# psycopg2 escaping characters

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgres query that looks like the following, and runs find on psql:

```
select 
    gcaseid,
    count (*)                          as N,
    array_agg(distinct nvchquestion)   as questions,
    array_agg(nvchanswer)              as answers
from
    case_script,
    case_script_answer
where
    case_script.gscriptid = case_script_answer.gscriptid and
    nvchquestion ilike '%blood pressure%'
group by
    gcaseid
order by
    N desc
;
```

Now, I wanted to have a similar query in Python, And this is what I came up with:

```
import psycopg2

def getAnswers(question):

    query = '''
            select 
                gcaseid,
                count (*)                          as N,
                array_agg(distinct nvchquestion)   as questions,
                array_agg(nvchanswer)              as answers
            from
                case_script,
                case_script_answer
            where
                case_script.gscriptid = case_script_answer.gscriptid and
                nvchquestion ilike %s
            group by
                gcaseid
            order by
                N desc
            ;
    '''%(r"'%%s%'")

    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='sos' user='postgres' host='localhost'")
    cur  = conn.cursor()

    cur.mogrify(query, (question,))
    # cur.execute(query, (question,))

    # result = cur.fetchall()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print getAnswers('blood pressure')
    print 'done'
```

Now, when I ran this query, I got the error:

```
$ python updateTable.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updateTable.py", line 39, in <module>
    print getAnswers('blood pressure')
  File "updateTable.py", line 27, in getAnswers
    cur.mogrify(query, (question,))
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 442
```

Not sure what is happening. Anyone can clarify please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%%` in your query to represent `LIKE` wildchars:

```
execute(" ... ilike %%%s%%", [question])
```

Or surround your value by `%`s in your value:

```
execute(" ... ilike %s", ['%' + question + '%']
```

See the [docs about parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up using!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest it to pass the `%` concatenated to the parameter as suggested by [@piro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42979809/131874):

```
query = "select 'x' ilike %s"
print (cursor.mogrify(query, ('%x%',)).decode('utf8'))
cursor.execute(query, ('%x%',))
print (cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Output:

```
select 'x' ilike '%x%'
True
```

But if you want to keep the parameters clean use `format`:

```
query = "select 'x' ilike format('%%%%%%1$s%%%%', %s)"
print (cursor.mogrify(query, ('x',)).decode('utf8'))
cursor.execute(query, ('x',))
print (cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Output:

```
select 'x' ilike format('%%%1$s%%', 'x')
True
```